# NServiceBus audit cleanup not working

Tags: nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus 5.2.16 and I have run into a problem with audit log cleanup. In the ServiceControl Management Utility the audit retention period is set to 30 days. However, the RavenDB database keeps growing with each day and in ServiceInsight I can see succeeded messages older than 30 days, so I suspect that old messages are not deleted from the database. What can I do to limit the size of the NServiceBus RavenDB database?

Comment: There is no limit, however, can you try and update ServiceControl, to the latest version? http://particular.net/downloads

Comment: I'm already using the latest version (1.23). I contacted Particular support about this issue. I'll post an update once I get any information from them.

Comment: I also noticed this issue using the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue by deleting the entire Raven database and restarting ServiceControl. This created a new database and after that old audit entries are properly deleted by ServiceControl.

I did get some useful information from Particular support. You can control the audit cleanup process by settings in the `ServiceControl.exe.config` file. Particularly, the `ServiceControl/ExpirationProcessTimerInSeconds` and `ServiceControl/ExpirationProcessBatchSize` settings are useful as they allow you to schedule the cleanup process more often or increase the maximum number of items deleted in each batch. You can find more details on those settings in the [NServiceBus documentation](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/creating-config-file#data-retention-servicecontrol-expirationprocesstimerinseconds).

Additionally, you can monitor the cleanup process in ServiceControl's log files. However, first you need to increase the logging verbosity to at least `Info`. This can be done using the `ServiceControl/LogLevel` setting in the `ServiceControl.exe.config` file. After changing the log level, you should see log entries similar to the ones below in the files in ServiceControl's `Logs` directory.

```
2016-10-26 09:49:06.2652|77|Info|ServiceControl.Infrastructure.RavenDB.Expiration.SagaHistoryCleaner|Batching deletion of 0-499 sagahistory documents completed.
2016-10-26 09:49:06.2808|77|Info|ServiceControl.Infrastructure.RavenDB.Expiration.SagaHistoryCleaner|Batching deletion of 500-715 sagahistory documents.
2016-10-26 09:49:06.4996|77|Info|ServiceControl.Infrastructure.RavenDB.Expiration.SagaHistoryCleaner|Batching deletion of 500-715 sagahistory documents completed.
2016-10-26 09:49:06.4996|77|Info|ServiceControl.Infrastructure.RavenDB.Expiration.SagaHistoryCleaner|Deleted 716 expired sagahistory documents. Batch execution took 11635ms
2016-10-26 09:49:06.4996|77|Info|ServiceControl.Infrastructure.RavenDB.Expiration.ErrorMessageCleaner|No expired error documents found
```